# Complete layout is not visible while designing in android

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I used  **scroll view** to display many controls.while designing it hides some controls. **I know it is must,** but it leads to problem, becoz  **scroll bar is not working at design time.** how can i see all the control at design time? or how can i scroll down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create your own custom preview, go to Graphical Layout> editing config: select Custom Screen, then create new screen preview according to your maximum size

Comment: i dont want to create new custom layout.it should work for small device. my problem is i cant see all controls at design time.

Comment: see first you can put all the controls on layout(ie custom size so that all controls are visible) arranged it as per required, once done then put them in your Scroll view

Comment: @ hotveryspicy ok im searching for any other way exists.. anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Scrollbar cannot visible in graphical layout but yet want to see layout then
>   please change your screen size from graphical layout top bar and if you cannot
>   see graphical layout then choose maximum api level in graphical layout.