# Graphical Layout shows null Pointer exception

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I have a UI design for an application. As we know that there are two view while designing a UI for an app in android in eclipse one the xml view and other the graphical layout. i am having a problem that i cannot get graphical layout of my xml. it shows a null pointer exception when i switch to graphical layout. Any suggestions..?

Comment: Does the text view show any errors?

Comment: @ huntsfromshadow No errors, the app runs fine. but graphical layout is not sown.

Comment: To make it clearer, i cannot see controls at design time. Any help..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are using some custom drawable(ie either shapes or style). it is not shown at design time but you will able to see when you run the project

Comment: i am doing this for different dpi's like ldpi, mdpi and hdpi. the problem persists with hdpi only. the design is visible in graphical layout, but don't know why not for hdpi.

Comment: hdpi is for larger screen so make environment accordingly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826362/complete-layout-is-not-visible-while-designing-in-android/6826444#6826444

Comment: Graphical Layout> editing config: select Custom Screen, then create new screen preview according to your maximum size

Comment: but i cant find editing config on my eclipse screen. please guide me through the procedure. ThankS

Comment: Oh i found that...Thanks buddy...nice addition to my knowledge.

Comment: first switch to graphical layoutt> editing config: select Custom Screen on the top of device window you will able to see

Answer (score 4):

I think you might find that the `View.isInEditMode()` function is what you are looking for.
Use it on any view that you have a reference to in the `Activity`.
If it returns true, don't attempt to get the reference that you were trying to get.
It's a little hard to tell if this will fix it for you, but you should definitely try this.